# TikZ line caps and bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf

When TikZ draws a path with `line cap = butt`, it contributes a small space to the bounding box in each end of the line with length the width of the line (i.e. the width the same line with `line cap = rect` would have).

(Edited with an example suggested in the comments)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2cm] (0, 0) -- (10pt, 0);
\draw [ultra thin, red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent TikZ from taking the inexistent line caps into account when updating the bounding box?

Comment: Sorry but I don't seem to be able to reproduce what you describe here. When I draw lines like you did, the bounding box is the same, whether with `butt` or `round`, or even `rectangle`, which seems to be normal, since the bounding box doesn't take neither the line width nor the cap in account. Could you please post a complete MWE and a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: @SebGlav I think the point is, that if you draw a thick line with `butt`, the bounding box will extend half the line width beyond the ends of the line, so you essentially get a bounding box which includes empty space. Try for example `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[line width = 2cm] (0, 0) -- (10pt, 0); \draw [ultra thin, red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`  Jaeya would like the bounding box to include only the black line, not the extra space.

Comment: Exactly what @TorbjørnT. said :)

Comment: It is not the case that the bounding box is correct for `line cap=rect`. This is only true if the lines are vertical or horizontal. To see this, consider this slight modification of @TorbjørnT.'s example. `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2cm,line cap=rect] (0, 0) to[bend left=0] (10pt, 10pt); 
\draw [ultra thin, red] 
(current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`. So it is not easy to fix this, I think.

Comment: Fair enough. For my application though, I only need vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: What [user240002 demonstrated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593487/tikz-line-caps-and-bounding-box#comment1488856_593487) is still the same problem: currently `pgf` [adds half the line width to the bounding box if the path is stroked](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/d835e0312028e7e398626bdd77e5effeaab280f0/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex#L112-L131).