# Why length of text in node affects/misplaces the previous draw position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-node, tikz-positioning

I almost know why the length of text in a node affects/misplaces the previous draw position: I guess the text of node shifts `(0,0)` position. But I have no idea how to force text start from beginning of a new line without affecting the previous draw position.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.9mm , gray] (0 ,-0.75) -- (0.95\linewidth ,-0.75);
        \draw[violet] (0,-1.5) node[fill=red,inner sep=0pt] {SSSSSSSSSSSSSS};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've fixed it using `anchor= west` but still there is a small white space from left approximately 2pt.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.9mm , gray, anchor=west] (0 ,-0.75) -- (0.95\linewidth ,-0.75);
        \draw[violet] (0,-1.5) node[fill=red,inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] {SSSSSSSSSSSSSS};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The "SSS..." is *centered* (you do not specify any anchor) around the coordinate `(-0.25,-1.5)`... the text on the node will not move the current draw position.

Comment: Coordinates only indicate positioning relationships in each `tikzpicture`. They don't have impact on how the picture is positioned on page. For example, `text \tikz\draw (0,0) -- (1,1); text` and `text \tikz\draw (3,4) -- (5,6); text` have the same output.

Comment: Place \node-s first. Don't abuse labels at lines as \nodes. Spend some tim on the introduction at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf .

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: I know that. But in one `tikzpicture` environment I think it must be positioned correctly without affects of node text.

Comment: Seems what you want is to specify node `anchor`, which is by default `center`. Thus in your example the center of node is at `(-0.25,-1.5)`. Try for example `\node[anchor=base west, ...]`. Also note there's no "new line" in a tikzpicture, only coordinates. Perhaps you can typeset node text outside of the rule tikzpicture, using `\fcolorbox` or another tikzpicture?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: `anchor` option does nothing. without any change. I also added that node text inside of another `tikzpicture` but output is same as above. (between two tikzpicture I've added `\vskip10pt` to force linebreak)

Comment: @C.F.G I’m a bit confusing. Can you describe your expected output/layout in more details?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: I've fixed it using your hints but still there is a small white space from left approximately 2pt. Do you know what  produces this white space?

Comment: @C.F.G Edit question to show what's your input and output now?

Comment: @C.F.G See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593487/tikz-line-caps-and-bounding-box#comment1488786_593487. Using `\fill` would overcome that.

Comment: The excess space on the left might be because the line overshoots its coordinate.  Try changing the line cap on the line (I think you want butt, but off the top of my head I'm not sure).  Also, the anchor on the line is doing nothing.